# apt-vim Plugin FileNotFoundError

Tags: json, linux, macos, vim

I'm going through the manual installation for Vim's, apt-vim plugin and when I try the command `apt-vim install -y`, brew is installed and I get the following error: `-e:1: '$(' is not allowed as a global variable name`. However, the installation completes and then another error crops up when I try `apt-vim init` as directed by the installation guide.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/cssummer16/.vimpkg/bin/apt-vim", line 805, in <module>
    apt_vim.main()
  File "/Users/cssummer16/.vimpkg/bin/apt-vim", line 785, in main
    self.process_cmd_args()
  File "/Users/cssummer16/.vimpkg/bin/apt-vim", line 758, in process_cmd_args
    self.MODES[mode]()
  File "/Users/cssummer16/.vimpkg/bin/apt-vim", line 534, in first_run
    shutil.copy('vim_config.json', VIM_CONFIG_PATH)
  File "/Users/cssummer16/anaconda/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 235, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/Users/cssummer16/anaconda/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'vim_config.json'
```

In my `apt-vim` file, the global `VIM_CONFIG_PATH` is set to `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_ROOT_DIR, 'vim_config.json'))`. Here is my `vim_config_json` file, which should be the same as the one I got from the apt-vim repository.

```
{
    "global": {
        "depends-on": [
            {
                "name": "vim",
                "recipe": {
                    "darwin": [],
                    "linux": [
                        "sudo apt-get install -y vim"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "git",
                "recipe": {
                    "darwin": [],
                    "linux": [
                        "sudo apt-get install -y git"
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "brew",
                "recipe": {
                    "darwin": [
                        "ruby -e \"$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)\""
                    ],
                    "linux": []
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "python",
                "recipe": {}
            }
        ],
        "install-target": "~/.vimpkg/bundle"
    },
    "packages": [
        {
            "depends-on": [],
            "name": "pathogen",
            "pkg-url": "https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen.git",
            "recipe": {
                "all": [
                    "mkdir -p ~/.vim/autoload",
                    "curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "depends-on": [
                {
                    "name": "ctags",
                    "recipe": {
                        "darwin": [
                            "curl -LSso ctags-5.8.tar.gz 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctags/files/ctags/5.8/ctags-5.8.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=iweb'",
                            "tar xzf ctags-5.8.tar.gz",
                            "cd ctags-5.8",
                            "sudo ./configure",
                            "sudo make",
                            "sudo make install"
                        ],
                        "linux": [
                            "curl -LSso ctags-5.8.tar.gz 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/ctags/files/ctags/5.8/ctags-5.8.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=iweb'",
                            "tar xzf ctags-5.8.tar.gz",
                            "cd ctags-5.8",
                            "sudo ./configure",
                            "sudo make",
                            "sudo make install"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "name": "tagbar",
            "pkg-url": "https://github.com/majutsushi/tagbar.git",
            "recipe": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code block in the `apt-vim` file which assigns all the global path variables.

```
import json, sys, os, re, shutil, shlex, getopt, platform, stat, ast
from distutils.util import strtobool
from subprocess import call, check_output, CalledProcessError

HOME = os.path.expanduser("~")
SCRIPT_ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(HOME, '.vimpkg'))
VIM_ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(HOME, '.vim'))
BUNDLE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(VIM_ROOT_DIR, 'bundle'))
SRC_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_ROOT_DIR, 'src'))
BIN_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_ROOT_DIR, 'bin'))
VIM_CONFIG_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_ROOT_DIR, 'vim_config.json'))
SCRIPT_EXE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BIN_DIR, 'apt-vim'))
```

There are is just one copy of the vim_config.json file in ~/.vimpkg. If someone could point me in the right direction for troubleshooting this installation, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you printed the value of `$VIM_CONFIG_PATH` in shell? Is it the same as the path of json file?

Comment: Yeah, `print(VIM_CONFIG_PATH)` yields `/Users/cssummer16/.vimpkg/vim_config.json`.

Comment: Is the output of SCRIPT_ROOT_DIR same as VIM_CONFIG_PATH ?

Comment: No, `print(SCRIPT_ROOT_DIR)` yields `/Users/cssummer16/.vimpkg`.

Comment: I edited the question to show the block in the apt-vim file which creates all the path global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer of `apt-vim` here.

It's unfortunate you're seeing this bug.  Not entirely sure why it's happening but it appears to be an issue with the automated installation of `brew` (see vim_config.json --> brew recipe).

As a workaround, try installing `brew` first with the official install command from [brew.sh](http://brew.sh/):
`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Then, try starting `apt-vim init` once more. If you continue having issues, please open an issue on [apt-vim's GitHub page](https://github.com/egalpin/apt-vim/issues). Thanks!